# How to optimize displaying Facebook & Twitter profile images on a social site?

Tags: mongodb, facebook-graph-api, amazon-s3, twitter, social-networking

I'm working on a social site that shows latest comments/likes/tweets/etc from Facebook & Twitter and displays them in a timeline. This is pretty much like the Facebook newsfeed, except it also has Twitter, Yelp and possible other sources mixed in so we can't use Facebook's plugin here.

We can cache the comments/etc but the profile images are a real challenge here as they keep changing. Would really appreciate your input on the following two points:

1) If we use the image url (e.g. `<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{user}/picture />`) directly in the comments box, then it'll mean potentially 100s of image urls resulting in 100s of HTTP connections and a very slow loading page. Any one have any suggestions to avoid this?

2) If we were to cache these images and generate a sprite or base64-encode them in JSON, any pointers on how best to store them in MongoDB or Amazon S3 would be awesome. I'm new to both, but something tells me 1000s of small files is going to cause fragmentation. At this point, I'm thinking of putting them in a Mongo table as a 50x50 image shouldn't be very big (less than 5k). Anyone see any issues with it?

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging the liveness and slimplicity of option 1), I've seen many sites recently "deferring" the loading of images.  For example, if you visit [this site](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/set-up-iis-7-to-run-a-secure-site-locally---https/21), you will see that the images "fade in" as the user scrolls the content into view.  In this case, the site developer is lazy-loading the images using the [Lazy Load jQuery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.lazyload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

...

$("img.profileImage").lazyload();
```

The idea here is that the browser only makes the image requests when it's necessary to do so (ie. when the image is actually on screen), and not right away on page load.  There are many javascript framework plugins to accomplish this, I'm not suggesting one over the other (matter of fact, the one I linked to purports to be broken), I'm just pointing you in the direction of something along these lines.

Comment: Thanks ckittle. This is definitely better than trying to load all images in a single shot.

Comment: @Karan You're welcome.  Don't forget to accept this answer if it fits your requirements.